# How to resolve this Project build error: Non-parseable POM error?

Tags: xml, spring, maven, pom.xml, spring-starter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU2YV.png)

Project build error: Non-parseable POM .m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\1.5.17.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.17.RELEASE.pom: in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got > (position: END_TAG seen ...\n>... @3241:12)

Here is my pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wirpo.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
   <parent> 
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.17.RELEASE</version>
     </parent>
    
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use spring-boot in version 2.X instead of 1.x cause 1.X is already defined EoL (August 2019)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your spring boot pom got corrupted somehow. Just try to delete your dependency directory - .m2\repository\org\springframework\boot and re ingest the dependency via mvn -U clean install

Answer (score 0):

Just do a project right button -> Maven -> Update Project